# Obsolete a RPM in Yocto

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, recipe

I would like to obsolete a rpm in Yocto. According to me another RPM is required to push the one i dont need anymore (obsoletes it).
How this should be done?
I read about option RREPLACES_${PN} (http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html). Tried several things without success.
Is this option the right one for this purpose at all?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Remove a RPM, or replace a RPM with another one?

Comment: I want to remove the RPM.